# Printing class attribute

Tags: python

Printing a class attribute from a function defined within the same class.

```
class person:
  name = "xyz"
  def show(self):
    print(self.name)

a = person
a.show()
```

Output:

```
TypeError: person.show() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Why the above code is throwing error while the code below is working fine?

```
class person:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def show(self):
    print(self.name)

a = person("xyz")
a.show()
```

Output: `xyz`

Comment: Because `show` still isn't a _class method_ in your first example. Either decorate it with [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) (and rename the parameter `cls`) or create an instance to call the method on `person().show()`.

Comment: I get it in the first example works using @classmethod . But I want to know the difference it creates when using def __init__(self) and name = "xyz". Because that's the difference between the two examples I gave.

And adding just () in the second last line of the first example also works. Please explain why adding () worked is it just the syntax or something more?

Comment: In the first example it's a _class attribute_ and an _instance method_ (hence making it a class method fixes the inconsistency). In the second it's an _instance attribute_ and an _instance method_. _"is it just the syntax"_ - what do you mean "just"?! "Adding ()" is _creating an instance_.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are trying to access something that has not been set, which is the name of the particular instance of the class.

Το define that this is a class method you need to use the respective decorator.

```py
@classmethod
def show(cls):
  print(cls.name)
```

You can name cls as you like btw, but it is common to use cls for class attributes and self for instance attributes/methods

If you do not need to this other ways to access the attribute would be

```
a.name
person.name
```